# How can I split an array into chunks but have it fill each array by going one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm using this function to create chunks of an array:

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size) {
    let results = [];
    while (myArray.length) {
        results.push(myArray.splice(0, chunk_size));
    }
    return results;
}
```

However, if we assume that the original array is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and I'm chunking it into 3 parts, I'll end up with this:

```
[
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]
]
```

But, I'd instead like it to chunk into the arrays jumping between the three, ex:

```
[
    [1, 4],
    [2, 5],
    [3, 6]
]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: "chunk into the arrays jumping between the two"  ? could you explain what you mean. Happy to help, but I'm confused. Just every other?

Comment: @zfrisch I jumbled my words in my original post, just edited it. It may make more sense now with the examples.

Comment: `const chunkArray = (myArray, chunk_size) => myArray.reduce((p, c, i) => (p[i % chunk_size].push(c), p), Array(chunk_size).fill().map(e => []));`

Comment: is it `chunk_size`, or `chunk_count`, because although the code says the former, the question really describes the latter.

Comment: also, a well-behaved version of this function shouldn't mutate the input array.

Comment: @ASDFGerte why not `Array(chunk_size).fill([])` ?

Comment: @Alnitak because having an array where each index points to the same array is not useful here.

Comment: Please add an attempt at creating chunks with offset.

Comment: @ASDFGerte doh!  Good point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size) {
    let results = new Array(chunk_size);
    for(let i = 0; i < chunk_size; i++) {
        results[i] = []
    }
    // append arrays rounding-robin into results arrays.
    myArray.forEach( (element, index) => { results[index % chunk_size].push(element) });
    return results;
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const result = chunkArray(array, 3)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the remainder of the index with the wanted size for the index and push the value.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    size = 3,
    result = array.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        var j = i % size;
        r[j] = r[j] || [];
        r[j].push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Elegant & minimalistic. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
function chunkArray(src, chunkSize ) {
  const chunks = Math.ceil( src.length / chunkSize );
  const chunked = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < src.length; ++i) {
    const c       = i % chunks;
    const x       = chunked[c] || (chunked[c]=[]);
    x[ x.length ] = src[i];
  }

  return chunked;
}
```